# PowerShell update nested value

Tags: powershell

I have the following output from a PowerShell command and want to update the value for EmployeeID
[image: Unfiltered output]

I can filter the output with `$test.identifiers | where {$_.name -like "EmployeeID" }`
[image: Filtered output]

But if I try to update the value with

```
$test.identifiers | where {$_.name -like "EmployeeID" } | foreach {$_.values.value = "098324"}
```

I get an error
[image: Error]

**How can I update this nested value?**

Comment: `... | foreach {$_.name = "098324"} `

Comment: looks what you are looking for is in a hashtable… I constructed a small hashtable to illustrate how to get the data:  $x=@{id='1';value='123';isObfuscated="False"}     ; $x['value'] ; $x['id']

Comment: @iRon That changes the name and not the value

Comment: @Tom Getting the data is not the problem $test.identifiers.values.value gives me this. But updating the values is what I'm trying to do

Comment: does it work if you treat as a hashtable like this   $test.identifiers.values['value']="098324"

Comment: Unfortunately not, gives the following error: Cannot convert value "value" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`$_.values` contains an *array* (or collection) objects, which explains why you can *get* (read) the `.value` property, but not *set* (write) it** (see below).

If you expect the array to have just *one* element, simply use `[0]` to access that element directly:

```sh
$test.identifiers | where {$_.name -like "EmployeeID" } | foreach {
  $_.values[0].value = '098324'
}
```

If there are *multiple* elements, use
`$_.values | foreach { $_.value = '098324' }` to assign to them all, or, alternatively in PSv4+,
`$_.values.ForEach('value', '098324')`

---

In PSv3+ a feature called **[member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375)** allows you to **access a property on a *collection* and have the property values from the individual *elements* returned** as an array.

However, that **only works for *getting* properties, not for *setting* them**.

When you try to set, only the collection's *own* properties are considered, which explains the error you saw - an array itself has no `.value` property.

While **[this asymmetry is by design](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5271)**, to avoid potentially unwanted bulk modification, the error message could certainly be more helpful.

---

**Simple reproduction of the problem**:

Create an object with property `one` containing a single-element *array* with another object, with property `two`:

```sh
$obj = [pscustomobject] @{ one = , [pscustomobject] @{ two = 2 } }
```

The default output looks as follows:

```sh
PS> $obj

one
---
{@{two=2}}
```

The outer `{...}` indicate an *array*, as in your case, and what's inside is a
hashtable-*like* notation that PowerShell uses to represent custom objects.

*Getting* the nested-inside-an-array object's `two` property works as intended:

```sh
PS> $obj.two
2
```

Trying to *set*  it *fails*:

```sh
PS> $obj.two = 2.1
The property 'two' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
```

To set, use `.ForEach()`, for instance:

```sh
PS> $obj.ForEach('two', 2.1); $obj

one
---
{@{two=2.1}}
```

Comment: Thanks! for your very extensive answer! $test.identifiers  | where {$_.name -like "EmployeeID" } | foreach {$_.values.ForEach('value', '098324')} did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it this way with the full object path:

```
$test.identifiers | where {$_.name -like "EmployeeID" } | foreach {$_.identifiers.values.value = "098324"}
```

Comment: I did, but no joy. Gives the error: The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

Comment: `$_` in the `foreach` (`ForEach-Object`) script block represents the element of input collection `$test.identifiers` currently being enumerated, so using `$_.identifiers` is incorrect.