# Adding constant string to string obtained in ForEach loop from hashtable of custom class object doesn't work as expected

Tags: powershell, class, object, foreach, hashtable

I have a Projects class defined as below:

```
class Projects{
    [string]$Name;
    [string]$FolderName;
    [string]$RemoteRepo;
    }
}
```

Then I create a hashtable:

```
$Prj  = @{"A1" = [Projects]@{Name = 'A1'; FolderName = 'B1'; RemoteRepo = 'C1'}}
$Prj += @{"A2" = [Projects]@{Name = 'A2'; FolderName = 'B2'; RemoteRepo = 'C2'}}
$Prj += @{"A3" = [Projects]@{Name = 'A3'; FolderName = 'B3'; RemoteRepo = 'C3'}}
$Prj += @{"A4" = [Projects]@{Name = 'A4'; FolderName = 'B4'; RemoteRepo = 'C4'}}
```

Then, for every value in the `Prj` hashtable, I want to extract the `FolderName` value, add a constant string let say `"www"` to it and display it.

To do so I'm doing like that:

```
ForEach ($p in $Prj)
{
    ($p.Values).FolderName + " www"
}
```

Instead of expected result:

```
B1 www
B2 www
B3 www
B4 www
```

I'm getting this:

```
B1
B2
B3
B4
 www
```

My questions:

1. Why?
2. How to do to get the expected result.

Comment: As an aside: [try to avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026)

Comment: [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) allows you to access a property on a collection and have the property values from the individual elements returned. ***However*, that only works for getting properties, not for setting them.** See: [PowerShell update nested value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51994110/1701026)

Comment: `$Prj.Values.foreach{ $_.FolderName += " www" }`